# Shape key animation + Shrink wrap + High Res Model?

Tags: animation, shape-keys, shrinkwrap

I would like to use a shape key to animate the mouth of my character.
I have the Hi res model targeted by the shrink wrap modifier on the low res model.
This works as intended with rigging but when trying to create a shape key for the mouth I'm unable to select verts, polys or lines on the low res model. So, I tried creating the shape key on the low res model first then applying the shrink wrap. The animation works but distorts the hi res model badly. I have no idea what I'm missing here or if what I'm trying is even possible. I have been unable to find any tutorials on this. Answers and links to tutorials are greatly appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: You *finish* the retopo before making any shapekeys.  Finishing the retopo means applying any modifiers, like SW, used to make that retopo, and probably baking textures.  After, you should be able to safely delete the high poly.  Then, make shapekeys on your low poly only.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Thanks for your response. So once the SW and Subdivision modifiers are applied is it the bake that retains the detail on the low res model? If so I need to learn how to bake.  Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Uhh, yeah.  (You lose some detail, unavoidably; baked normals, maybe ambient occlusion, will restore some apparent detail.)  Focus on tutorials dealing with how to make a low from a high, and don't worry about your shapekeys until after you're done with that.

Comment: Could not find the answer to this using Sub Surf modifier but the search for that lead me to the multi res modifier. Using the Multi res mod + SW. After applying the SW modifier you keep the Muti res modifier but you can delete the Hi res model and create shape keys on the low res model with full detail. Thanks Nathan. Your reply put me on the right path.